# Trying to get a Json response from an API using AsyncTask I always get null result

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am stuck with this so any help would be much appreciated.

I am trying to get a Json response from an API using AsyncTask but I always get null result.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private String fetchURL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=...";

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


  new MyAsyncTask().execute(fetchURL);

}

public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    String inputLine;
    String result;

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String stringUrl = params[0];

        try {
            //Create a URL object holding our url
            URL myUrl = new URL(stringUrl);
            //Create a connection

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection =(HttpURLConnection)
                    myUrl.openConnection();

            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(1000);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1500);
            urlConnection.connect();

            //Create a new InputStreamReader
            InputStreamReader streamReader = new
                    InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            //Create a new buffered reader and String Builder
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


            //Check if the line we are reading is not null
            while((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null){

                stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
            }
            //Close our InputStream and Buffered reader

            reader.close();
            streamReader.close();
            //Set our result equal to our stringBuilder
            result = stringBuilder.toString();



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return result;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What does the stack say when you get the null result?

Comment: Add this to your catch block: `result="Exception: " + e.getMessage();`.

Comment: `stringBuilder.append(inputLine);` that should be `stringBuilder.append(inputLine+"\n");`.